# How to snap horizontally and vertically (including primary monitor on dual setup) in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

How do you snap horizontally and vertically (including primary monitor on dual setup) in Ubuntu 16.04?  Ubuntu normal setup only snap vertically on left of primary monitor and to the right of second monitor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001444/virtual-split-screen-on-ubuntu