# How can I duplicate my desktop and show it side-by-side on a single screen?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a custom VR device I'm testing and I'm looking to do something which should be simple with my desktop monitor settings. Essentially I want to go from a regular desktop, this:

[image]

To having this screen repeated side-by-side split down the middle, like this:

[image]

And it's literally just a real-time copy of the desktop.

For reference, I am using a 800 x 480 display, in case that's relevant.

Ideally I would like to put my computer permanently into this display mode, so that every time it boots up it's like this automatically.

Answer (score 3):

Most of what I am writing will be coming from [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/115076/how-to-vertically-split-widescreen-into-two-virtual-workspaces-on-ubuntu-gnome), or more specifically [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/956643/554026).

***Since you are using raspbian, you're going to have to use FakeXRandr, which has FakeXinerama built-in:***

Download FakeXRandr from [this link](https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr). Unzip the archive,`cd ~/Downloads/fakexrandr-master` and run

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev build-essential python3-gi python-gi-dev python-gi-cairo
```

You will now have the tool `fakexrandr-manage` available to use. Launch that from terminal, and you will see the following GUI to configure your monitor setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for an answer. I will test this later today and let you know!

Comment: Hey so some comments. I am on a raspberry pi, which I thought would be similar enough, but maybe isn't. I can do most of the steps, except the `nautilus` stuff, and I can't open that screen display setting page. Raspbian seems to have a much simpler one. Any ideas how I can get it work on the RPi? Appreciate the help so far.

Comment: Running `pcmanfm` instead of `nautilus` should work. As for the settings menu being different, what OS are you running, exactly? It looks like Ubuntu 18.04 but you say raspbian?

Comment: Yeah, the screenshot was generic because I thought all linux would be similar enough for something like this. But I am indeed using Raspbian, which (to my knowledge so far), doesn't give me the "Displays" window like it does on your screenshot. I should have specified exactly, my mistake. But if I can get this running on Raspbian with my generic 800x480 display I will happily accept this answer and close the question :)

Comment: @JDS I added Raspbian instructions, please lmk if it works.

Comment: OK, here is the result, not quite there with xrandr: `pi@pi-robot:~ $ xrandr --current
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 800 x 480, maximum 7680 x 7680
DSI-1 connected primary 800x480+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   FIXED_MODE    60.05*+
pi@pi-robot:~ $ ^C
pi@pi-robot:~ $ xrandr --output DSI-1 --same-as DSI-1
xrandr: loop in relative position specifications
` Any ideas? I have very little idea how to properly use xrandr, could be my mistake.

Comment: @JDS I overhauled the answer with a new way. Please try

Comment: I'm having issues installing fakeXrandr unfortunately: `./configure
XRandR version is 1.5.1
The path to the real XRandR library is /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libXrandr.so.2

ERROR: Failed to find a suitable directory for the fakeXrandr library

You must place the library into the library search path, in a directory preceeding
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf. In your system, this leaves the following candidates:
/opt/vc/lib, /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf,
None of these contains `local', therefore I won't autoconfigure the installation to one
of these directories. Either ...`

Comment: (this is the output from `sudo make`)

Comment: @JDS I would ask this over at [RaspberryPi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), then. This is no longer similar enough to Ubuntu for me to feel comfortable advising that you change files around. Feel free to link this post in your question for context.

Comment: No worries appreciate the help. I am trying to install Ubuntu Mate and get it running on my Pi so perhaps I can go back and try your previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

**One post suggest this** (Refer this link: [(virtual) split screen on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001444/virtual-split-screen-on-ubuntu))

As far as I know you can only split your screen for two windows at a time. Either one on the left and one on the right, Or one on the top and one the bottom. And there are shortcuts associated for these actions which are:

For vertical split:

Ctrl + Win + ←→

For horizontal split:

Ctrl + Win + ↑↓

---

**In in case this does not work** As You have not mentioned you are using Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04. You can refer this post "[(virtual) split screen on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1001444/virtual-split-screen-on-ubuntu)"
& "https://superuser.com/questions/115076/how-to-vertically-split-widescreen-into-two-virtual-workspaces-on-ubuntu-gnome" Here [FakeXRandR](https://github.com/phillipberndt/fakexrandr) is suggested for 18.04.

---